# How to insert a tuple/list into a database using SQLITE3?

Tags: database, sqlite, flask, tuples

I have several pieces of data collected from a form I want to enter into my database. However, one of those data pieces is a list created from how many checkboxes a user has pressed. When I try and insert this into a list I get the error "sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.". My code stops working at "cur.execute(sql, listing).

I've tried changing the type of data piece it is, but I need the tuple to stay as it is. I have tried to use cur.executemany but it didn't work.

```html
title = request.form['item_name']

platform = request.form.getlist('platform_list[]')

con = create_connection(DATABASE_NAME)

listing = (title, platform)

sql = """INSERT INTO items(id, title, platform) VALUES (NULL,?,?);"""

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(sql, listing)

con.commit()

con.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite does not have a "list" [datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Here are two options that may solve the problem:

- Transform the list to a string as with `str = ",".join(platform)`
- Transform the list to a JSON string as with `json.dumps(platform)`

It would depend on how the data will be used when it is `SELECT`ed back.

If you want one row in the database per platform, you would use `executemany`. You would have to construct `listing` differently so that each array element contains all the insert parameters. Something like `listing = [(title,x) for x in platform]` for instance.